# How can I left align the extra columns in an Xpages Data View

Tags: xpages

DataViews really provide almost everything I want in Xpages views EXECPT that I cannot control how extra columns appear. They are always right aligned. Is there a way to make them left aligned? I don't want a tremendous amount of space between the summary column and the extra columns.

Comment: Check the HTML for CSS classes that makes it possible for you to distinguish extra columns from summary columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The column sizing seems in that way, because the width of the Summary columnn is set by renderer (100% for usual dataview).

[image]

If you could remove that `width: 100%` style, the sizing of column would be usual.

There are a couple of ways to do that but neither is elegant.

Using CSS will not be a nice technique, but it will work. Since we can't address that specific column with a class name and width style is inline, we can define myRowStyle as the rowStyleClass for our dataview control and use the following rule:

```
tr.myRowStyle td { width: auto !important; }
```

Now, we will consider some problems of course. Any inline or CSS definition for other columns will be overridden by this rule. Also if you use any table within these columns, they will be effected too.

You can define a more specific selector for minimum side effect, but this will not work for older browsers (e.g. IE8):

```
tr.myRowStyle > td:nth-child(2) { width: auto !important; }
```

Alternative way is to write a short dojo script which finds the second TD within every row and remove width property. You might put such as a script just after the data view. For browsers with a slow connection might see a flickering on rendering stage for this case.

Comment: I think this would work but it seems like it is a lot of work and, as you say, inelegant. I marked it as correct, but I think I am going to stick with a view control, although I really like how the data view looks and works - EXCEPT for this one thing.